# Difference between Java custom JRE and Java native image

Tags: java, spring, jvm, graalvm, spring-native

In addition to developing classic services on Spring Boot, I want to know Java with it environment better.
When I began to study portability, I came across such concepts as custom JRE (jlink, jmods) and native image (GraalVM, Liberica NIC).

As I understand :

- Custom JRE for creating distribution folder with executable file. In folder only necessary dependencies. It arrived in Java 9
- Native image for creating executable all in one JAR

Which of them should be used in which cases?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should know what a JRE (Java runtime environment) is. Basically, it includes everything required to run Java applications that are already built. A [JDK (Java Development Kit)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/) is a superset of a JRE, adding the tools for developing Java applications.

With [`jlink`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/282), you can create JRE images. This means you are creating a Java installation that is capable of running your Java program. This can be done in a way so it only contains the necessary modules. [`jpackage`](https://openjdk.org/jeps/392) allows you to create an installer for such a JRE.

On the other hand, a native image is a version of your code that's compiled and optimized for a specific target platform. Typically, it's a single executable file that runs your code. When [creating a native image](https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/), it takes your application and converts (compiles) it to a platform specific executable (unlike `jlink` which creates a JRE that is able run your "normal" JAR).

Native-image does not generate a JAR but an ELF/EXE file which can be executed on your device without a Java installation while `jlink` just creates a (minimal) Java installation capable of running your application.

It should be noted that native-image comes with a few limitations. For example, remote class loading is not possible and if you use [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html), you [need to specify what to reflectively access at compile-time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/graalvm/enterprise/21/docs/reference-manual/native-image/Reflection/).